# Adding pause on infinite smooth modified Owl Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, owl-carousel

What I'm trying to do is to build an infinite smooth slider of images. I started with code at https://codepen.io/mdrezwanferdous/pen/wpNZxN, because I want to have same effect. 
But I'm having a hard time to figure it out how to add hover effect. When mouse is over the single picture, slider should immediately stop. And when mouse leaves, slider should continue looping.

What I tried to do so far:

```
$('.owl-carousel .owl-item').on('mouseenter',function(e){
  $('.owl-carousel').trigger('mouseover.owl.autoplay');
  $('.owl-carousel').trigger('stop.owl.autoplay');
  $('.owl-carousel').trigger('stop.autoplay.owl');
  $('.owl-carousel').trigger('autoplay.stop.owl');
})
```

But none of these four lines worked.

Is there an easy way to fix this? Is this even possible with Owl Carousel?

If no, is there any free slider that can do this? I tried with Slick slider, but it didn't work great ( the problem was because on hover slide didn't stop immidiately. Instead it waited for slide transition to be completed).

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The example you are trying to follow seems overly complicated. I would suggest to use Slick.js here.

Library docs should be more than enough to get you started:
https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Focus on those 2 settings (`autoplay`, `pauseOnHover`), that I believe is what you are looking for ( See Autoplay section) :

```
$('.autoplay').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 2000,
  pauseOnHover: true
});
```

Let me know if you have any more troubles understanding your problem